# Calculating force changes from single hanging system to a pulley

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

In modifying an indoor clothes drying way (after laundry), I simplify the problem as follows:

A single hanging system as shown (before). The point bearing stress is P. It hangs 100 lbs of weights.

Now it’s changed using a pulley, with another end fixed to wall, as shown at right (after). The angle is given.

Both P and P' attached to the ceiling.

Question: Is P' receiving 2 times of the forces, in the new system? Assuming the old system, when hang 100 lbs onto it. P received 100 lbs of stress. (ignore the weights of the additional accessories in the new system)

After it’s changed, does P' receive 200 lbs? What’s the right way to calculate the new force that P' received? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Why do you think that the stress is different?  Yes, vertical stress is different, as is horizontal, but the resultant stress (or tension as we call it) would still be the same.

Comment: @QuIcKmAtHs,  Thank you for the comment.  I was thinking the P' is being pulled by both the 100 lbs and the wall. so doubled it.

Comment: No problem.  Problems regarding pulleys can be really confusing at times, so it is important to pay attention to details and have a strong grasp of the concept.

Comment: The tension in  the rope is 100 lbs in each case.  In the second case the rope on the right side adds both a vertical and a horizontal force at the point of support. ( each 100 cos45)

Comment: QuIcKmAtHs, R.W. Bird, thank you both for the knowledge! would you consider to post an answer so we can close this question?